# How do you pass a string array into QtConcurrent::run?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qtconcurrent

In my program QtConcurrent Run does not accept my array of strings or my array of bools. Do I need to convert them into QByteArrays for the data to be passed in?

According to the documentation this works:

```
extern QString someFunction(const QByteArray &input);

QByteArray bytearray = ...;

QFuture<QString> future = QtConcurrent::run(someFunction, bytearray);
...
QString result = future.result();
```

In my program this does not work:

```
extern void test(string args[]);
string args[7]={"blue"};
QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run(test, args);
```

Error: C2075-- array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful to illustrate your problem.

Comment: please illustrate your problem with example

Comment: Sorry I should have put more effort into my initial post.

Comment: Why `string args[7]` rather than `std::array`? Why would you *ever* prefer a raw C-style array over `std::array` or `std::vector`?

Comment: I did not know about that but I will look into it. So far in c++ i have only used vectors and c-style arrays.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Answer (score 0):

Never use C-Style Arrays in QtConcurrent::run. Use C++ std::array instead. Thank you Jesper Juhl!